# Why do I need to redeclare overloaded virtual functions?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, virtual

I have a base class with two overloaded functions `f(void)` and `f(int)`. The class `Derived` implements `f(int)` by calling `f(void)`. `Derived2` implements `f(void)` only.

The compiler rejects the implementation `Derived::f(int)` because it wants to call `f(int)` but I provided no arguments because I want to call `f(void)`. Why does the compiler reject it? Why does adding the line `virtual int f(void) = 0;` fix my problem?

```
class Base
{
public:
  explicit Base(void) {}
  virtual ~Base(void) {}

  virtual int f(void) = 0;
  virtual int f(int i) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  // provide implementation for f(int) which uses f(void). Does not compile.
  virtual int f(int i) {puts("Derived::f(int)"); return f();}
  // code only compiles by adding the following line.
  virtual int f(void) = 0;
};

class Derived2 : public Derived
{
public:
  // overwrite only f(void). f(int) is implemented by Derived.
  virtual int f(void) {puts("Derived2::f(void)"); return 4;}
};

int main(void)
{
  Base * p = new Derived2();
  int i0 = p->f();  // outputs Derived2::f(void) and returns 4
  int i1 = p->f(1); // outputs "Derived::f(int) Derived2::f(void)" and return 4
  delete p;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Derived::f` hides `Base::f`s. Given `return f();` in the body of `Derived::f(int)`, the name `f` is found in the scope of `Derived`, then [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) stops. The names in `Base` won't be found and participate in overload resolution.

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.

You can add `using Base::f;` to introduce the name from `Base` into the scope of `Derived`.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  using Base::f;

  // provide implementation for f(int) which uses f(void).
  virtual int f(int i) {puts("Derived::f(int)"); return f();}
};
```

Comment: Or even better not to use the same name for those functions.

Comment: I do not know what OP is performing, but use static and dynamic polymorphism at the same time is not a good idea IMHO. But if OP wants hard way, who gonna stop him?

Comment: I like your answer. Maybe you can explain the difference between my redeclaring and your "using Base::f" solution. Does your solution have any advantages?

Comment: @Slava There are a lot of Derived2 classes, Derived is an adapter to avoid rewriting a lot of code. Hence the names are fixed.

Comment: @Fabian Given the code you've showed the effect is the same. The difference I can think of is if there're many overloaded functions `f` in `Base`, with `using Base::f;` you don't need to declare every `f` in `Derived`.

Comment: @Slava Yes I agree it might be worth reconsidering the design when mixing overriding and overloading.

Comment: @Fabian "There are a lot of Derived2 classes" I do not see how that dictates to have the same name for methods `f(void)` and `f(int)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then `Base::f()` but not `Derived2::f()` will be called, I think it's not what OP wants.